# return monodimensional-array from multidimensional

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$array=array( 0=>array('text'=>'text1','desc'=>'blablabla'),
              1=>array('text'=>'text2','desc'=>'blablabla'),
              2=>array('text'=>'blablabla','desc'=>'blablabla'));
```

Is there a function to return a monodimensional array based on the $text values?

Example:

```
monoarray($array);
//returns: array(0=>'text1',1=>'text2',2=>'blablabla');
```

Maybe a built-in function?

Comment: you want to turn all values of a particular sub-key in the array? Change your 'blablabla' to something more unique, because it's not clear which of the 4 blablabla's you want returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return array with first values in inner arrays:

```
$ar = array_map('array_shift', $array);
```

For last values this will do:

```
$ar = array_map('array_pop', $array);
```

If you want to take another element from inner array's, you must wrote your own function (PHP 5.3 attitude):

```
$ar = array_map(function($a) {
    return $a[(key you want to return)];
}, $array);
```

Comment: First two examples are also PHP4 stuff ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
function GetItOut($multiarray, $FindKey)
{
   $result = array();
   foreach($multiarray as $MultiKey => $array)
        $result[$MultiKey] = $array[$FindKey];

   return $result;
}

$Result = GetItOut($multiarray, 'text');
print_r($Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to define your own function, with a `foreach` loop. You could probably use one of the numerous php [array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), but it's probably not worth your time.

The `foreach` loop would look something like:

```
function monoarray($myArray) {
    $output = array();

    foreach($myArray as $key=>$value) {
        if( $key == 'text' ) {
            $output[] = $value;
        }
    }
    
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of your keys never changes (i.e.: `text` is always the first one), you can use:

```
$new_array = array_map('current', $array);
```

Otherwise, you can use:

```
$new_array = array_map(function($val) {
    return $val['text'];
}, $array);
```

Or:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $new_array[] = $val['text'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://codepad.org/drYeJQHF):

```
function monoarray($array)
{
    $result = array();

    if (is_array($array) === true)
    {
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $value)
        {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With PHP, you only have to use the function print_r();

So --> print_r($array);

Hope that will help you :D